# How to extend styled component with an arrow function

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm looking for a way to pass an arrow function to my styled component which extends an existing component, but there doesn't seem to be an overload that supports this. Is this a current limitation in the library?

I want to turn this

```
const $Element1 = styled($Element)`
  left: 8px;
  ${(props) => props.condition && `top: 2px;`}
`;
```

into this:

```
const $Element1 = styled($Element, (props) => ({
   left: 8px;
   top: props.condition && '2px` || undefined
});
```

Comment: It's not a limitation, it's just that they didn't design their API to work like this. Can I ask why do you want to do this?

Comment: I thought to not have to repeat the props parameter in an inline function in multiple places, it just looks nearer in my opinion

Comment: You don't have to repeat it, you can return multiple lines of css rules from one function.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: I'm going to post it as an answer, so I can properly format the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple conditional styles and don't want to repeat the function, you can do it this way:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const $Element1 = styled($Element)`
    right: 4px;

    ${(props) => css`
        left: 8px;
        ${props.condition && `top: 2px;`}
        ${props.condition2 && `bottom: 2px;`}
    `}
`;
```

Comment: That looks neat! So the `css` template string method is the key here. I'd change it though to have it at the very start, before the `right: ` css rule.

Comment: @silkfire Of course you can do it however you want, it's just an example.

Comment: I would also destructure props into ({condition, condition2}) to make it even neater.